# How to have smooth (horizontal) transition on a c3js dynamic chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph, c3.js

I started playing with c3js hoping to get a good looking dynamic chart. While testing it I noticed that the transition between each `load` functions seems to happen without any sort of transition. I also tried to use the `flow` function but got to the same result. I couldn't find anything on this topic only but basically is there a way to change this behavior and have a smooth transition when a new data point comes in?

You can see my example here:

```
        transition: {
            duration: 0
        },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g4cq6pg0/1/

When I actually enable transition it works well (horizontally), until I start removing some data to add new metrics, then things go south. Instead of just transitioning horizontally it also transition vertically which makes things very hard to look at (350 is the default value):

```
        transition: {
            duration: 350
        },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g4cq6pg0/2/

How can I force a smooth horizontal transition only?? Here is an examples (using D3 only) of what I mean:

http://bl.ocks.org/simenbrekken/6634070

Comment: I havent played with c3.js but have d3.js. It looks as if you update the path instantly but the nodes transition as expected. Perhaps find a way to transition the paths rather than immediately change them ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy I agree, but I couldn't find any guidance on how to achieve that. I'm using c3's update method which seems to be the one to use with dynamic data.

Comment: with d3, you would implement enter() exit() ill see if i can find anything on c3.js

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the line's moving, but the points are just bobbing up and down vertically to fit the current values, not moving with the line...

Have a look at the question here --> [Dynamic timeseries C3js chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155966/dynamic-timeseries-c3js-chart/37217712#37217712)

The flow api lets you do what you ask but has a significant bug (see my answer there), so adjusting the questioner's own answer may be your best bet for the smooth horizontal transition

PS. If you also want to stop the y axis auto-sizing, you'll need this in the chart declaration:

```
axis: {
        y: {
            max: 1 // translates to 100% on the y axis
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and couldn't figure it out in JSFiddle. I also opened your link and found an example but still the animation is not smooth. I edited the original question and gave an example of what I meant: http://bl.ocks.org/simenbrekken/6634070 (using C3). I'm wondering if I shouldn't just start using D3 now.

Comment: Yeah, the animation is jerky because 1) it updates every 2 seconds but the animation is only for 750ms, that could be changed but also 2) the y-axis is animated after the graph is animated horizontally, so can't really do a continuous feed like you ask for. Though another choice for real-time data, but lacking the smooth spline effect, is cubism, it's by the same guy who wrote d3 - https://square.github.io/cubism/

Answer (score 0):

c3js has a .flow method specifically for this: http://c3js.org/samples/api_flow.html

Be aware it starts to freeze if you switch to other tab and return after a while.

Comment: I tried flow but I couldn't get it to look fluid.. the pauses are still thee. Not sure if I missed something?

Comment: Didn't achived it fast. Try to play with the duration option (present both for the whole chart and the flow method) to be close with the data update frequency.